# C# easy math function

Tags: c#

I`m trying to calculate a percent of successful jobs in total.
Code:

```
int total = valid + invalid;
int percent = (valid / total) * 100;
if (percent == 0)
{
  MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(total) + ":" + Convert.ToString(valid));
  break;
}
```

If all job are successful, the percent is 100%.
If one job is bad, percent is 0 and i get messagebox with:
9:8

8/9*100 = 88.888, not 0.

```
int percent = Convert.ToInt32((valid / total) * 100);
```

gives no result. Please, help me.
I am Russian, so sorry for bad English.

Comment: You're doing integer division...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing both `valid` and `invalid` are defined as `int`s. In that case, the result of all calculations will be `int`s as well.

You either need to cast one of the values to floating point type in the operation or, and this would probably be easier, define one of the values as a floating point type to begin with:

```
double total = valid + invalid;
int percent = (valid / total) * 100;
```

Comment: The other option worth noting (if all you want is an int) is that you can just change the order of the calculations. (valid*100)/total will work (though of course you must note that the final result will be a turncated integer and not rounded in the usually expected way).

Answer (score 3):

your valid and total variables are int which means your valid / total division will truncate to an integer, which will always be 0 in your situation.

If you changed one of the variables to a double it would allow the division to perform the way you expect.

```
int percent = Convert.ToInt32(((double)valid / total) * 100);
```

Now, that would cause your if clause to not work properly anymore, so you'd have to change that to probably check that it's not 100

so instead of

```
if (percent == 0)
```

you'd want to do something like

```
if (percent != 100)
```

instead

Answer (score 1):

You just need to much around with the casting so that you're not doing integer division and looking for a floating point result, eg:

```
    double percent = ((double)valid / total) * 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your line to be:

```
int percent = (int)(((float)valid / (float)total) * 100f);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you operate on [integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer) (целое число), but to have the division work properly you should use the [rational number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number).

When you perform 8 / 9, you have 0 because eight is lower then nine so the result will be between 1 and 0. To represent number between 1 and zero you have to use float type.

```
float total = valid + invalid;
```

Now the division look like this:

```
 8 / 9.0
```

but this is still not the end, if you assign the float number to integer you will have a compiler warning.

```
float result = (valid / total) * 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
float total = valid + invalid;
float percent = (valid / total) * 100;
if (percent == 0)
{
  MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(total) + ":" + Convert.ToString(valid));
  break;
}
```

**Edit:**

Changed percent to float too.

Comment: The reason is an int divided by another int always gives you an int.  If you divide an int by a float, you'll get a float.  So your value gets rounded to the nearest int (either 0 or 1) and then you multiply that by 100.

Comment: You forgot a cast to int there

Comment: Wouldn't the above give a compiler error on the second line? (implicitly converting 'float' to 'int')

Comment: Yea, making "percent" a float would probably be a good idea, since the original post said he wants "88.888".  Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your ints to floats before doing calculations.

```
int percent = Math.Round(((float)valid / (float)total) * 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some kind of floating-point math rather than integers.

```
int total = valid + invalid;
int percent = ((decimal)valid / (decimal)total) * 100m;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the result of `(valid / total)` is an `int` (whole number), as `valid` and `total` are `ints`, so the result of the division will truncate to a whole number.

The solution is to force one to be a `float`, `double` or `decimal`:

```
int percent = (int)Convert.ToInt32(((float)valid / total) * 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `float` instead of `int`:

```
float percent = ((float)valid/(float)total) * 100.00f;
```

**Edit**:
Yes, I forgot to cast `vallid` and `total` to float.

Comment: Won't that have the same issue as (valid/total) would be an int, before converting to a float to do the multiply.

Answer (score 0):

one of your factors needs to be a floating point value, otherwise you end up with an integer as a result.

```
int total = valid + invalid;

int percent = (int)((valid / (float)total) * 100);

if (percent == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(total) + ":" + Convert.ToString(valid));
    break;
}
```